# OpenGraph now showing shares count for some pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've got a problem on a website I've made.

Facebook opengraph is not showing the shares count for some pages...

For example, I have only the id and the share count here:
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.richardmarazziphoto.com/portfolios/epoca-colour-2/ 
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.richardmarazziphoto.com/portfolios/amourica-2/

But on these 2 pages I have all the other infos, but not the shares count:
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.richardmarazziphoto.com/portfolios/yyz/ 
http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.richardmarazziphoto.com/portfolios/south-of-the-border-2/

The pages have the same template (it's a website in WordPress and all those pages use the same php template file...)

Did I do something wrong?! How can I fix it?
Why a page that has basically the same template is showing different information?

I've checked on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
and I don't have any error on my og tags..

Thanks a lot!
Stefano

Comment: no one has ever had a problem like this one?

Comment: I have the same issue, still no solution.

Comment: I wonder if is there a direct support contact on facebook where we can ask for more info. I've searched for a direct contact but with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I had the same issue. What I did was tried running the URL through the graph without the trailing slash. For example:

http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.richardmarazziphoto.com/portfolios/yyz

This would show the count. If you run it with the slash like you had, it wouldn't.

I thought I fixed the issue. It works for my older pages, but the newer ones aren't working.

Here is an example:

http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/forgot-your-password-how-to-recover-a-lost-password-in-wordpress

Not sure what FB has been doing lately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem. (Not WP, but PHP template pages). Absolutely no OG errors in the debugger ... I've Googled the issue and re-read the OG docs to no avail. The only pattern I can see is that any page published prior to a certain date works, everything after does not. Possible that I unwittingly changed something vital and FB is caching info from the old versions? However, as I said, the debugger scrape is current and there is no difference in the old and more recently published pages.

No shares showing:
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.aspenbusinessjournal.com/article.php?id=7873

Shares showing:
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.aspenbusinessjournal.com/article.php?id=7800

Comment: ok, so I'm not the only one having this issue.... I wonder if is there a direct support contact on facebook where we can ask for more info. I've searched for ad direct contact but with no luck...